# How to calculate the new XY coords and rotation every frame based on the speed of two motors?

Tags: javascript, math, graphics, 2d, physics

Im trying to figure out how to simulate where the new XY coords and rotation will be based on the speed of two motors. e.g if the left wheel is at 50% speed and the right wheel is at 80% speed then it will go forwards but slightly to the left.

[image]

I'm using JavaScript to draw onto a canvas.

```
function setMotors(left, right){
    var motorLoop = setTimeout(() =>{
        rotation = //new rotation
        x = //new x
        y = //new y
        clearCvs();
        drawRobot(x, y, rotation);
    }, 1000/60);
}
```

Comment: for that you need to know the speed in `[units/s]` and distance of the wheels in `[units]`. The distance difference over time will give you arc-length giving you the angle of rotation change. However unless the ratio is not precisely set to match the turning radius a drift will be present making computation slightly inaccurate. You can also lose the grip completely if too off and high speed is present. That is why we have differentials in cars ...

Comment: @Spektre So say the distance between the vehicle is 30 pixels and the left wheel is travelling at 50 pixels/s and the right 80 pixels/s as in the example above. The difference being 30 pixels/s would the rotation of change per second = 30/30pi * 360?

Comment: I made an answer describing your example, but read with extreme prejudice as 
this is not my cup of tea so I might be wrong or missing something ...

Comment: @Spektre Ok thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see it like this:

[image: turn]

where `l0,l1` are the arclengths traveled by wheels, `d` is distance between wheels and `r` is turning radius of the first wheel leading to system:

```
omg * r    = v0
omg *(r+d) = v1
```

where `omg` is the turn speed `[rad/s]` so (unless I made a math mistake):

```
r    = (v0*d)/(v1-v0) [units]
omg  = (v1-v0)/d      [rad/s]
```

using your values:

```
r    = (50*30)/(80-50) = 50.0 [pixels]
omg  = (80-50)/30      = 1.0  [rad/s] = ~57.3 [deg/s]
```

Ignoring all possible grip/drift issues ... Signs of the results determine on which side the robot turns ...

Comment: How would You compute the sliding friction in such a case?

Comment: @deblocker that is complicated as you would need to change to Newton/D'ALembert integration so your motors would create Torque/Force, Grip frictions will lower the Force a bit according to material coefficients so if your motors are 30% and 80% it no longer means your speeds from wheels are 30% and 80%. On top of this the width of the wheels cause another friction to rotation of heading changing the rotation radius a bit. And once speeds are over the grip threshold you lose control entirely and can forget about simulation completely (you would need position and orientation sensor for feedback)